# Cannot see project.clj in leiningen project using intelliJ idea?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea, la-clojure

I am using IntelliJ Idea 12.14 Community Edition on Windows 7.
I have installed leiningen separately.

I was trying to create a new project using idea.
I have also installed the La Clojure plugin and re started Idea several times.

Neither do I find options to create a Clojure project nor is the "project.clj" being visible to  open project dialogue in intelliJ for an existing  project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the project won't be openable until you also install the Leiningen plugin.  The wiki shows it as browsable in the default repository but I didn't find it.  I wound up just downloading it from here:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=5029

After install, the .clj file was openable as a project.

Comment: I did that sometime back but I am liking LightTable 0.4 more.
I think for Clojure, it should be stable enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is no integration with leiningen, so you cannot open a project.clj directly. If you really want to use IDEA, I would recommend to either:

- Use maven and the [clojure-maven-plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin)
- Use `lein pom` to generate a pom.xml and then import that pom. This will give you a project with the proper dependencies and LaClojure will give you a repl, autocomplete, code navigation, etc. You will need to run `lein pom` when you change dependencies and use the command line for any other build commands.

Comment: I was following these steps in the jetbrains wiki. It nowhere mentions something like this.
Anyways.. I will try this as well.
Thanks.